# Static fixed name resolution for specific domain name

Tags: dns, localhost

Is it possible to setup a static domain name resolution in Ubuntu 20.04?

AFAIU when domain name is to be resolved, the clients send DNS request to some local service (systemd-resolved?). I want it to resolve a specific domain name to a specific IPv4 address.
For example, abc.server.com -> 192.168.1.15, such that DNS servers in the Internet are not queried and the resolution process takes place solely at my PC.

Just putting it into /etc/hosts does not work, because this file is only used by some command line tools, but when domain name is to be resolved in general, there is some DNS request to 127.0.0.1:53 or something like that, and /etc/hosts is ignored.